# Make height same as dynamic width using JavaScript didn't work

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, height

I'm using Bootstrap in my project and tried to make a square from Bootstrap col, but it didn't work and always has a different gap of width size and height size in it like 94.11px and 94px.

i want to make the ratio 1:1 width:height. but didn't work

HTML

```
<div class="content_image col-xs-3 squarethis"></div>
<div class="content_description col-xs-9 followheight"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var st = $('.squarethis').width();
$('.squarethis').css({'height':st+'px'});
$('.followheight').css({'height':st+'px'});
```

anybody have a clue?

```js
var st = $('.squarethis').width();
$('.squarethis').css({'height':st+'px'});
$('.followheight').css({'height':st+'px'});
```

```css
.squarethis{
width:30%;
  float:left;
background:#ccc;}
.followheight{
width:70%;
  float:left;
background:#999;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="squarethis">asd</div>
<div class="followheight">asd</div>
```

Image down below

[the gap between width and height from this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZOjh.jpg)

Comment: What exactly _"did not work "_ ?

Comment: it has a gap between width and height size like 94.11px and 62px. @Rayon

Comment: Can you share an example/fiddle ?

Comment: @Rayon i can't it always show "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", when i put it in JsFiddle

Comment: Include `jQuery` library as you are using it ;)

Comment: @Rayon i tho it included already, added the fiddle.

Comment: `followheight` has `70%` width..

Comment: @Rayon meaning? let me explain something, at squarethis div has a different height and width, its not exact square (180.79x181)px. that's the thing i want to ask, how to make this exact square.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `height` of the element in the callback of the `.css` method([**`.css( propertyName, function )`**](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function))

***Update:*** After few tests, I could make out that by the time `width` is assigned to the element, we also get scrollbar on the page which causes change in the `width` of the element as we are assigning it in **`%`**, setting `overflow : hidden` will give you expected result!

```js
$('.squarethis').css({
  'height': function() {
    return $(this).width()
  }
}).text(function() {
  return $(this).width() + ' x ' + $(this).height();
});
$('.followheight').css({
  'height': function() {
    return $(this).width()
  }
}).text(function() {
  return $(this).width() + ' x ' + $(this).height();
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.squarethis {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
}
.followheight {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="squarethis">asd</div>
<div class="followheight">asd</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/fb41hfvx/)

Comment: thx for ur effort, but it doesn't answer my question. if u can inspect the squarethis div, u will see the different of it width size and height size. it's not square

Comment: @riverrhun What is not ? Are you kidding?

Comment: it's not working, im not, im using display flex and adjustment center with overflow hidden in .squarethis div but it change nothing still not square.

Comment: i checked ur updated fiddle, it's not. thx for ur effort tho. u can inspect the div right? u will see 'number'x'number' that define div width and height, and it is different number

Comment: @riverrhun I can.. And difference is about 0.4 px.. And we don't really consider floating numbers when unit is px right ?

Comment: indeed, exactly 0.4px different but if u using bootstrap and it moving to device view or a smaller div, it has a big gap within width and height size. i can't put an image in here, but i want to show u

Comment: i just added the image with link, never knew it can upload an image. please check it out.

Comment: @riverrhun, I can not make any better demonstration that this... Click on __ Run code snippet__ and check!

Comment: i like u Rayon, thx for ur effort. still the decimal numbers make me feel so wrong.

Comment: @riverrhun That is because of having width set in %

Comment: ya absolutely, u r right man. so the answer is we can't make square right?